# To produce output in single line

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where I need to output the lines obtained in single line separated by comma.The code snippet below depicts the services startype and the output we get is listed in newline.

The code snippet is :

```
$ServicesName ='servicename1', 'servicename2', 'servicename3', 'servicename4', 'servicename5', 'servicename6', 'servicename7', 'servicename8', 'servicename9' 

Get-Service -Name $ServicesName | Foreach-Object -Process {
    if($_.StartType -ne "Disabled"){
        "Service {0} is not disabled" -f $_.Name
    }
}
```

The output will be like :

Service servicename1 is not disabled

Service servicename2 is not disabled

Service servicename3 is not disabled

Service servicename4 is not disabled

Service servicename5 is not disabled

Service servicename6 is not disabled

Service servicename7 is not disabled

Service servicename8 is not disabled

Service servicename9 is not disabled

How can we produce output in single line separated by comma?

Comment: What you are asking is "How do I add output to array in a loop".

Comment: @Drew, Yes I need to add output array in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `-join` operator like below.

```
$Message = (Get-Service | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.StartType -ne 'Disabled'}) -join ',' 

Write-Output -InputObject "$Message is not disabled"
```